# Text movement in Text fields

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts

I moved to OS X several years ago, and have noticed that due to the way they set up keybindings, you get some niceties when it comes to navigating any text area (for example the URL field in your chosen web browser).

An example of this is if I press `ctrl+a`, then I navigate to the beginning of the line, and if I then press `ctrl+k`, it deletes the line (You may recognise these as emacs commands).

Is there a way to get this same functionality (possibly by registering a 2nd ctrl that is ignored by general key-commands captured by applications) in linux?

Answer (score 1):

Short: probably not.  Applications on a X Window desktop read key symbols and interpret them on an application-specific basis.  There are *conventions* for the key symbols (which a particular set of programs may follow), but nothing that *enforces* them globally.

Comment: Thanks, that's a little annoying. I was hoping it would be possible to mess around with a potential `hyper` key. I may have to hang around then. I have begun to find this functionality indispensable.

As an aside, does wayland allow for customisation of these attributes in any way? or would it be worth asking another question?